# How to publish message without waiting for response RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm new to RabbitMq and I just followed internet resource as a tutorial. here I have created two separate API for OrderRequest and OrderConsume. from the order request, I'm calling something like this.

```
IRequestClient<OrderRequest> _client;
public OrderRepo(IRequestClient<OrderRequest> requestClient)
{
    _client = requestClient;
}

public async Task<string> GetOrderList(OrderRequest orderRequest)
{
    string datas = "";
    try
    {
        using (var request = _client.Create(orderRequest))
        {
            var response = await request.GetResponse<OrderReponse>();
            datas = response.Message.orderName;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
    return datas;
}
```

and from the OrderConsume, I did something like this.

```
public class OrderConsumer : IConsumer<OrderRequest>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<OrderRequest> context)
    {
        OrderReponse request = new();
        try
        {
            var data = context.Message.orderName + " HelloWorld";
            request.orderName = data;
            
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

When I debugging the code Consume part working fine, but here you can see, I'm not passing any response from there. there for from the request API. I'm getting time out error.

```
Timeout waiting for response, RequestId: a1670000-a53b-c025-bd0b-08d9d52ca58a.
```

Actually I don't need any response from Consumer side, and just wanted to pass the request to consumer. I think I need to change my code here?

```
using (var request = _client.Create(orderRequest))
{
    var response = await request.GetResponse<OrderReponse>();
    datas = response.Message.orderName;
}
```

is it correct? but actually i don't know how to do it. please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your order command does not require a response, don't use the request client. Just publish the command and forget about it.

```cs
IPublishEndpoint _publishEndpoint;
public OrderRepo(IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint)
{
    _publishEndpoint = publishEndpoint;
}

public async Task<string> GetOrderList(OrderRequest orderRequest)
{
    string datas = "";
    try
    {
        await _publishEndpoint.Publish<OrderRequest>(orderRequest);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
    return datas;
}
```

Of course, in your original code you were actually using the response, so...

Comment: Hello sir, can you please check this and help me please, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70947157/how-to-pass-headers-with-rabbitmq-request